# Why volatility does not return anything from running linux_pslist

Tags: android, volatile, information-extraction, volatility

I have manage to extract the volatile memory from the android emulator using LiME and using volatility to further analyze the memory.

After running the command:

*$ python vol.py --profile=LinuxGoldfish3_4ARM -f /path/to/lime.dump linux_pslist*

I received the following:

*Volatility Foundation Volatility Framework 2.3.1
Offset     Name                 Pid             Uid             Gid    DTB        Start Time
---------- -------------------- --------------- --------------- ------ ---------- ----------*

May I know why nothing is being returned ?

Comment: Are you sure that the profile you used for volatility accurately reflects your emulator kernel?

Answer (score 0):

I would make extra sure that the profile you're using reflects the kernel that is running on your device. I had this same problem when creating a volatility profile that used a System.map file which didn't quite match what was on my Samsung S2 I9100T.

If you're interested in testing on a real device (or using a custom ROM in your emulator environment) I followed [these](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_integrated_kernel_building) [build](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_i9100) guides with the appropriate ROM and kernel downloaded from the [cyanogenmod git repo](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/) and was able to dump memory using [LiME](https://github.com/504ensicsLabs/LiME) and then successfully analyse it in volatility.